# How do I solve the "pygame.init()" error?

Tags: python, pygame

After I write "import pygame" no error comes up so I think I'm good to go but when I try to create a program and then I type "pygame.init()" an error comes when I run this code. I also ran this program in shell but it was working, no error was there. But I don't know for some reason it doesn't run when I try to create a program.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/pygame.py", line 1, in 
> import pygame
> File "C:/Users/LENOVO/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32\pygame.py", line 2, in 
> pygame.init()
> AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)

This is the error I am getting when I try to open a window in pygame and this is the code I wrote:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_moode((500, 500))
```

Comment: Try post the **error message** or the **full code**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you named your game's source file `pygame.py`. That causes `import pygame` to import that very file itself, rather than the *actual* `pygame` library.

Just rename the file to something else!

Comment: still not working I am getting the same error but with the different file name as I changed it "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/GROOT!/pragati.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/GROOT!\pygame.py", line 2, in <module>
    pygame.init()
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pygame' has no attribute 'init' (most likely due to a circular import)"

Comment: There is still a file named `pygame.py` in that folder. I said "rename", not "copy" :)

Comment: I renamed the file named pygame and it worked! Thank you so much sir !